# android:org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException:Connection closed without indication

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ftp, ftp-client

everyone,I am suffering this problem for 4 days..Help is needed...

I am developing an android program that intends to upload a file to a FTP server.

My developing environment: ubuntu12.04 + eclipse

I want to upload the file in a service. Now, the service can be started successfully.
here is the code of the upload method in service class.

```
public String ftpUpload(String url, String port, String username,String password, 
        String remotePath, String filePath,String fileName) {       
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();      
    FileInputStream fis = null;  
    String returnMessage = "0";  
    try{
        System.out.println("我看你能不能连接上！！！！");
        ftpClient.connect(url,21);        
        System.out.println("我草还真能连上！！！！！！");
        int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){              
            ftpClient.disconnect();
            System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        boolean loginResult = ftpClient.login(username, password);  
        int returnCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode(); 
        Log.v("returnCode",""+returnCode);
        System.out.println(loginResult);
        if(loginResult && FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(returnCode)){               
            ftpClient.listFiles("");
            ftpClient.makeDirectory(remotePath);  
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(remotePath);  
            ftpClient.setBufferSize(1024);  
            ftpClient.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");                    
            fis = new FileInputStream(filePath+"/"+fileName);  
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode(); 
            System.out.println("last step!!!!!!");
            ftpClient.storeFile("IwantYou", fis);                  
            returnMessage = "1";         
        } 
        else 
            returnMessage = "0";                      
    }
    catch (IOException e){              
        e.printStackTrace();  
        throw new RuntimeException("擦，还真没连上！！！",e);  
    } 
    finally{            
        try{                
            ftpClient.disconnect();  
        } 
        catch(IOException e){               
            e.printStackTrace();  
            throw new RuntimeException("关闭FTP连接发生异常！", e);  
        }  
     }  
     return returnMessage;  
}
```

here is the problems:

test on android device: successful

test on emulator

1. if the emulator and the FTP server are not in the same computer:successful
2. if the emulator and the FTP server are in the same computer: fail

so let's focus on this case..and some different options happens

1. if I connect real IP address(10.238.154.173) exception happens at
   connect method, here is the logcat:

   ```
   W/System.err( 1074): org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
   W/System.err( 1074): at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:313)
   W/System.err( 1074): at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:290)
   W/System.err( 1074): at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:392)
   W/System.err( 1074): at  org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:764)
   W/System.err( 1074): at  org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:169)
   W/System.err( 1074): at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:189)
   W/System.err( 1074): at com.example.hehe.FirstService.ftpUpload(FirstService.java:64)
   W/System.err( 1074): at com.example.hehe.FirstService$1.run(FirstService.java:36)
   W/System.err( 1074): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
   I/System.out( 1074): something is wrong!
   W/System.err( 1074): java.lang.RuntimeException: 擦，还真没连上！！！
   W/System.err( 1074): at com.example.hehe.FirstService.ftpUpload(FirstService.java:94)
   W/System.err( 1074): at com.example.hehe.FirstService$1.run(FirstService.java:36)
   W/System.err( 1074): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
   W/System.err( 1074): org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
   W/System.err( 1074): at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:313)
   W/System.err( 1074): at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:290)
   W/System.err( 1074): at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:392)
   W/System.err( 1074): at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:764)
   W/System.err( 1074): at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:169)
   W/System.err( 1074): at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:189)
   W/System.err( 1074): at com.example.hehe.FirstService.ftpUpload(FirstService.java:64)
   W/System.err( 1074):    ... 2 more
   ```
2. if I connect the IP(10.0.2.2) I can connect successful.but the
       storefile method failed.

I have google it for several days, all failed.

Any suggestion could be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: OK. Nobody answers.. I don't know why, After suffering it two days, The exception vanished without any change of code. OK .Hope my code can help someone.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can connect and as soon as I get to the `ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);` line, I get the connection closed. There is a Suppressed Inner Exception, which is `UnmodifiableRandomAccessList`, but I am not sure what that means, as I am just setting the file type.

Comment: Ah, the getReplyCode() helped. My error was really "Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption.".

Comment: Hi @fightwithbug, can please help me out on this, I am also stuck since 3 days, getting same exception while using commons-net-3.1 jar to connect FTP server, can't figure out how to fix this. Did you change anything? when your problem got fixed on its own?